# Shopware 6 Update product price via App Scripting

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

Is it possible to reduce the price of a product globally? Via a Shopware app?

I have tried it on the product-page-loaded hook, but its not working.

```
{% set price = page.product.getPrice() %}

{% do (price | first).getListPrice().setNet(10) %}
{% do (price | first).getListPrice().setGross(10) %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change prices globally with app scripts. You're not allowed to persist data from there.

- Your app may request the rights to update products via the api. Then you could change prices via the api on your app server, triggered by [webhooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#webhooks).
- You may react to the product being added to the cart and alter the cart using the [cart manipulation script services](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/script-reference/cart-manipulation-script-services-reference).

*Only* on the product page, you may alter the price but with the list price it depends on whether the product already has a list price. Keep in mind that the prices you set here will **not** stick, when adding the product to the cart.

```
{% set price = hook.page.product.getCalculatedPrice() %}

{% do price.assign({ 'unitPrice': 5 }) %}
{# will only work if product already has a list price #}
{% if price.getListPrice() is object %}
    {% do price.getListPrice().assign({ 'price': 10, 'discount': -5, 'percentage': 50 }) %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. But it is possible to change the price on the product page and also in the cart?

Comment: To a limited degree it is possible on the product detail page. I updated my answer. However you'll not be able to change the price in the cart. You'll have to add discounts or surcharges instead.